# How to delay sound in java

Tags: java, audio, wav

I have a wav file playing at the start of the program. The problem is, it plays to quickly, I need it to delay about 5 seconds and then play. The program is a quiz and the sound file says good luck so I basically need it to delay so the program can open and the person can read the tittle and the first question and then the sound plays.
Thanks

```
    static AudioClip soundTiger, soundApplause, soundGoodLuck;

    url = TFtest.class.getResource("goodluck.wav");
    soundGoodLuck = Applet.newAudioClip(url);
    soundGoodLuck.play();
```

Comment: Do you want to delay it synchronously or asynchronously?

Comment: I think you need to post more code so we can understand the program. If soundGoodLuck.play() just plays the sound, cant you just call this at a later stage? Or you can call Thread.sleep

Answer (score 1):

Add a Thread instance and use

```
 Thread.sleep(5000);
```

The Thread instance is required if you don't want that other components block